# How to make commandline arguments available in decorators using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

### Context

What I am trying to achieve is to have a decorator which, depending on a command line argument, will change how the test is run:

```
import pytest
from functools import wraps


def magic():

    # obtain extra_bit
    extra_bit = ...

    def wrapper(f):
        if extra_bit:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwars):
                f(*args, **kwars)
        else:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwargs):
                assert 0

        return test_func

    return wrapper
```

Calling this decorator as:

```
@magic(4)
def test_this():
    assert 0
```

The calling interface is important, as the commandline argument should not appear here (as the user of the decorator never does anything with it).

### Paraphrased from the pytest documentation

(https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html)

It is quite easy to make commandline arguments available as fixtures to test functions in pytest:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--extra_bit', action='store_true')

@pytest.fixture
def extra_bit(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--extra_bit')
```

and then using them in a test

```
def test_this(extra_bit):
    assert extra_bit
```

**However**, these fixtures only work when used in the definition of a `test_` function, and not for arbitrary functions in your test module.

### Question

How can I obtain command line arguments from pytest if not via `test_` function arguments/fixtures?

Comment: Command line arguments are available in `sys.argv`. But `pytest` looks at those too, and may complain if you provide options it doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer in short

Using `pytest_configure` one can make the option available in a `conftest.py` file.

#### conftest.py

```
import pytest

_EXTRA_BIT = False

def extra_bit():
    return _EXTRA_BIT

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--extra_bit", action="store_true")

def pytest_configure(config):
    global _EXTRA_BIT
    _EXTRA_BIT = config.getoption("--extra_bit")
```

#### testplugin.py

```
from conftest import extra_bit
from functools import wraps


def magic():

    # obtain extra_bit
    extra_bit = extra_bit()

    def wrapper(f):
        if extra_bit:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwars):
                f(*args, **kwars)
        else:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwargs):
                assert 0

        return test_func

    return wrapper
```

**EDIT:** The old answer below uses the **deprecated** `pytest.config` module.

### Answer in short

So it turns out that pytest does offer that functionality via the `pytest.config` module. The documentation for this is here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.config.Config. The function one can use is the `getoption` function.

### Adapted example

```
import pytest
from functools import wraps


def magic():

    # obtain extra_bit
    extra_bit = pytest.config.getoption('--extra_bit')

    def wrapper(f):
        if extra_bit:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwars):
                f(*args, **kwars)
        else:
            @wraps(f)
            def test_func(*args, **kwargs):
                assert 0

        return test_func

    return wrapper
```